# Is it ok to optimise my site for “freevideos” instead of “free videos”?

Tags: seo, optimization, strategy

I am optimizing my website for SEO and after doing some research on google keyword tool I found out that there are a lot of searches for glued keywords with very thew competition in the search results.

As an example:"free videos" has around 45,500,000 monthly searches with 92.600.000 result pages with exact match

But...

the keyword: "freevideos" has about 1,500,000 monthly searches with 128.000 result pages with exact match

As you can see the ratio searches/page results is very very high in the second example then in the first.

So the question is: aren't there any draw backs by optimizing for such a keyword? There are tons of such keywords with millions of searches with little to no competition. I already got a few visitis being on positions 70-100 so that makes me think that the numbers are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are drawbacks. In order to optimize your site for that keyword, you are going to have to use the word freevideos, as if it didn't have any spaces. That's going to look unprofessional.

What I would do is name your site "freevideos", or something with the word freevideos in it. It will still look unprofessional, but it will probably look better than if you used freevideos like you did that unintentionally.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the reply. I guess that will be the biggest drawback, this optimization will be viewed not only by the search engines but the users to. Someone said that I should do this for an internal page rather then the home page but I don't know if it will have the same impact on the google results.

Comment: @razvan if you do an internal page, the affects will be lessened, because not everybody will see it, but people coming from the search results page will still see it. Also, if this is the answer you're going with, can you accept it (click the check mark) so people know that you've solved the problem?

Comment: Ok, I will do that. I will optimize some internal pages and see how that plays out. Thanks for the help, you get the mark.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you're really getting the full picture with those figures.

1. Sites optimized for "free videos" will turn up for users searching for `freevideos`. Sites optimized for "freevideos" are much less likely to turn up in the results for `free videos`.
2. You can easily use natural synonyms for "free videos" (e.g. free movies, cost-free videos, public videos, free clips, etc.), but Google probably won't recognize any synonyms for "freevideos", making it much harder to optimize for the term without being spammy.
3. The top sites that perfectly match "freevideos" only match the term in their URL. And these sites only rank well for the SERPs where users search for `"freevideos"` (in quotes). I very much doubt those 1.5M monthly searches are for `"freevideos"` in quotes.

So the conclusion you drew might make sense from an AdWords/SEM POV, but probably not from an organic search perspective.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 1. The websites that turn up for "free videos" are the big websites, seems that google gives a portion of their authority to rank better on pages that are just as worse as every other page. 2. Yes, that will be an option but the ratio is much much smaller. 3. It's true that most glued keywords bring up more seearch results without the quotes but some are the same without the quotes. I belive that google has a threshold, if he indexes a fixed amount of websites for a glued keyword at one point he will consider it as a hole word because so many people use it

Comment: Anyway thanks for your opinion but I'm not ready to give up on this opportunity, yet. I feel like to many people are running from this but in a couple of years everybody will be in on it. I have already seen websites optimizing for bad keywords, probably glued keywords is the next step if google allows it. In the end I will probably go with the internal page optimization. I would buy a new domain that is optimized for that keyword but it will take to long for google to rank me up on that, and I don't want to wait anymore.